# Land use map to binary exclusion layer

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.6

I have a map (raster, tif file) with 7 land use classifications and 6 colors representing each classification.

The 7 classifications are

1. Land use 1
2. Land use 2
3. Land use 3
4. Land use 4
5. Land use 5
6. Residential
7. Urban

I would like to produce a binary exclusion layer (raster) that excludes land use 1.

To do this, I am trying to use the reclassify tool. However, the categories in the table are strange.

Under old values

1. 0-1
2. 1-2
3. 3-4
4. 4-6

There is no 'Residential' or 'Urban category' in this table.

So, how can I properly reclassify the data so that 'land use 1' is reclassified as 0 and everything else 1 (complies with the binary exclusion criteria).

I'm using Arcmap 10.6

Comment: What software are you using or do you have available to use? Any suggestions will be software dependent.

Comment: @Michael Stimson - I'm using Arcmap 10.6

Comment: Please edit your question rather than replying as an answer. I will add the ArcMap 10.6 tag for you.

Comment: If you have a spatial analyst license you can use Con https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z00000005000000 with a condition where land use equals 1 to write 0 otherwise write 1 to create a binary mask (sort of, it's not truly binary as it will have values of 0, 1 and possibly NoData). Another good option is SetNull where value not equal to 1 and 0 where equal to 1 so the data will be 0 and NoData. If you don't have a spatial analyst license you could use GDAL_Calc https://www.gdal.org/gdal_calc.html (last example).

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Con function in the Spatial Analyst toolbox such that if the value of your land class data is one, then the value in the output raster is NoData.  If the value is not land class one then the output is the same as the land class data.  As far as using the reclass tool...without seeing a screen shot of the tool... I suspect you just need to add more class breaks to cover your range of values.